# React Native: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' when trying to run on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app and when I try to run it on my android device i get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/myname/.android/build-cache.lock
```

I'm using the following versions:

- react native: 0.57.3
- Android studio: 3.2.1
- java: "1.8.0_191"
- distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
- macOS: Mojave 10.14.1

I tried to change Gradle versions but it didn't work. This is my `app/build.gradle`:

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: Have you ever successfully build any program with current configurations?

Comment: @AkshayPaliwal, this is my first time working on react native

Comment: 'java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException' this exception saying that there is some problem with permission, ex. like your sdk or some dependency doesn't have access for sudo/super user of your system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.Upgrade your gradle to :-

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

2.Delete gradle cache files. It can be in path like C:\Users\username.gradle\caches for windows users. For Unix like sys it will be ~.gradle\caches

Comment: I upgraded the tools to 3.2.1 and gradle to 4.6 (it asked me to do it) and now I get a different error `Cannot create directory /Users/myname/.android/build-cache/3.2.1`. In my .android folder I have 2 files, abdkey and abdkey.pub

Comment: Ok, I added manually build-cache/3.2.1, I changed the permission access to my `.android` folder, maybe some other random change and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the latest gradle version to solve this issue.

- Upgrade gradle build tools version in the project level `build.gradle` to **4.0.0 or higher**

  ```
  buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        ...
    }
  }
  ```
- Upgrade the gradle version in the `YourProject > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties` to **6.0.0 or higher**.

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
  ```